# MAX in Where Clause in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have SQL Query like this

```
SELECT WI.[WorkItemID]  ,[WorkItemNumber]  ,[ToDate]     
FROM [WorkItem] AS WI INNER JOIN  [WorkItemTrack] AS WT on WI.WorkItemID=WT.WorkItemID
WHERE MAX([ToDate]) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

and corresponing Entity Framework Query is

```
 workItems = from wi in workItems.Where(p => p.IsActive)
             join wt in entityCollection.WorkItemTrack on wi.WorkItemID equals wt.WorkItem.WorkItemID
             where wt.ToDate >= fromdate && wt.ToDate <= todate
             select wi;
```

Here I am not able to use MAX for wt.ToDate in Enitity Framework Query

Please help me

Comment: What is the use of MAX in where clause? Doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max in the where clause shouldn't work.

> "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference."

But if you want the top most result based on a certain column, try adding an order by said column, then take the top result of that set.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SqlServer.Max()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399163%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method. these are aggregate methods you can use

Example

```
SELECT VALUE SqlServer.MAX(p.ListPrice)
FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Product as p
```